# Key input lag when typing

Tags: keyboard, input

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 (and before that I had the same problem with 12.04)
on a Dell inspiron 9400 Intel Core 2 Duo T7200.
But when I am trying to type something the keys do sometimes not respond at all or the letter is repeated a lot in one short keystroke.
for example: when typing "Hello" this can happen: " Hlllllllllllllo"
The E in hello did not show up, and the second l repeated a couple of times.
This didn't happen when I used a live usb boot.
Does somebody have the solution for my  problem, because it makes the computer almost unusable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like this could be a duplicate of [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029256/19264)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. I sporadically have similar issues in Ubuntu 18.04; slow keys is off. When the issue is occurring, there can sometimes be a multi-second lag between when I press a key and when the letter appears, and then sometimes it'll repeat 2, 3... up to 10+ times; if I type fast enough, the repeats overlap. Other times keypresses will be missed entirely. Attempting to type `bleh my keyboard (or OS) is tripping` resulted in `blehh mmy keyeyboaarddddddd   (oorr  OS) is tripping`. Similar symptoms, but not the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried: System Settings - Keyboard - Select Typing TAB, adjust 'Key presses repeat when key is held down". Experimenting with Delay - try slide it a little to the right (longer). 'Speed' slider, will determine how fast it will retype, once the system understands you want to retype a pressed character, by pressing it 'long enough' following above mentioned setting.