# Multimedia keyboard with lag ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard

when I use the volume increase button when trying to type anything on the keyboard it has a lag the same happens when I am going to increase or decrease the volume.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04
Gnome shell graphic environment

does not happen in unity

Comment: Seems like duplicate of [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029256/19264)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but for Spotify.

Searching I found this: https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Delay-when-changing-volume/td-p/1589346

> Essentially PulseAudio is deliberately delaying global volume changes.
>   This can be changed:
>
> - Get a root terminal and edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`.
> - Find the setting "enable-deferred-volume", remove the semicolon at the start of the line if is commented out and set its value to "no"
> - This will enable instant global volume changes
> - Get a terminal with your normal user, restart the PulseAudio daemon:
>
>   ```
>    pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start
>   ```
>
> The man page warns about sound glitches that might occur when
>   switching off deferred volume changes. If you experience this, switch
>   it back on and adjust the delay settings to lower values until it
>   suits you.

Comment: The line "pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start " didn't work for me in 22.04. Instead, I had to reboot to restart pulseaudio. Now the delay when changing the volume is gone :)

Answer (score 2):

Could be a reported Gnome issue. Here's a possible solution, at least for users with a Brazilian keyboard: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1777708/comments/8

> After being annoyed by this bug for a long time, i started digging and found a workaround. Today i found that the bug is only present when i'm using certain keyboard layouts ("Portugues (Brasil)") and was not present when i changed the layout to EUA and language to English (need to set them both to English).
>
> After some digging i found out the culprit is the ScrollLock key and that can be fixed by editing the layout file, which in my case is found at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br`. The only modification i did was to remove or comment the line: `modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };`
> After that, set the language and layout back to Portugues (Brasil) and the problem was gone!
>
> No more delays between typings.
>
> PS: I tried this on Fedora, i will try this on ubuntu tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for this information... acredito que você seja Br, valeu mesmo a ajuda.