# obnoxious delay on hold volume up/down

Tags: gnome, sound, keyboard, 21.04, media-buttons

I'm on ubuntu 21.04

Something that's been grinding my gears since Ubuntu 17.10 is the added delay for hold volume up/down. Some guy at gnome thought he was being super clever but this is abominable.

so, to explain: if you hit the media key on the keyboard for sound up once you get an immediate response in sound up (regardless of how long the ui display takes to show)

but say you hit and hold the key because you're going to increase the volume by a lot. it does not go up. it does nothing for a while and after that wait period, starts to go up and stops when you let go.

I don't agree with the UX decision there. I don't know what that was supposed to accomplish, I actually tried to type my theory out but I had to delete it three times, I can't think of a reason that makes sense.

Anyways, since gnome and linux are super configurable I'm wondering if there's a way I can remove this delay.

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042357/multimedia-keyboard-with-lag-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: it's not that. as I said I don't have that bug. if I do by increments/multiple keystrokes, or just one keystroke there is no delay, the sound response is instant. This only occurs for me when I am holding down the key. it's by (bad) design.

Comment: If you feel that this is a bad design then you need to file it as a feature request as a bug report.

Comment: fair enough although linux being linux, I should have the right to fix in on my own end in the meantime, no?

Comment: You do have that right.  The source code for it should be available.  However, what ever controls the repeating of the media controls on a keyboard is beyond me since absolutely none of my keyboards that I have used have the repeat function on the volume controls.  If I press any of mine and hold them down, it does not change any further than the little bit of my first press.  Maybe your keyboard has that repeat for the media keys built into it?

Comment: that I did not know. I've never not had that functionality so I assumed it came with the OS not with the keyboard. what a bizzaro world we live in. why would holding down volume up not mean "keep increasing"???

Answer (score 2):

This here solved it for me:
https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Delay-when-changing-volume/td-p/1589346

The skinny:

- open `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`
- uncomment and set `enable-deferred-volume=no`
- on terminal: `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start`

On the [man page of pulseaudio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/pulse-daemon.conf.5.html) you can actually find an explanation why this even exists.