Ubuntu 24.04 with keyboard input lag
Good afternoon,
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my computer and since then I have been having problems with Wayland when using some applications. I haven't found a solution to the problem yet, so I am logging in using Xorg.
However, I am experiencing a very annoying issue with a significant input lag (between 2 and 3 seconds) every time the next key is different from letters and numbers and vice versa.
Example 1: If I am typing a text with alphanumeric characters and the next key is an accent mark, special character, backspace, enter, space bar, or cursor key, there is an input lag.
Example 2: If I am deleting text using Backspace or DEL, and the next key is an alphanumeric character, the same input lag occurs.
Example 3: If I am typing an alphanumeric text and then immediately type a punctuation mark, it generates an input lag.
Is anyone else experiencing the same problem using XORG on Ubuntu 24.04? Below are my machine's specifications:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64   Kernel: 6.8.0-39-generic

Shell: zsh 5.9

Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080

DE: GNOME 46.0

WM: Mutter

WM Theme: Adwaita

Theme: Yaru-blue-dark [GTK2/3]

Icons: Yaru-blue [GTK2/3]

Terminal: gnome-terminal

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X (12) @ 4.000GHz

GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 6700/6700 XT/6750 XT / 6800M/6850M XT

Memory: 6776MiB / 31997MiB


Edit
An important thing that i noticed is that the input lag also freezes for a short period of time any video that i'm watching on youtube

I am assuming that you have looked at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029256/

Yep ! Another thing that i noticed a while ago is that the input lag also freezes for a short period of time any video that i'm watching on youtube.

Same exact problem here. I hope you have solved the problem already. If not, may I can share my experience here.
The choice for Wayland turned the development of 24.04 to it, and this was made costing some (or much of) Xorg integration.
I couldn't find a solution while using Xorg, and decided to move to Wayland as recommended. In my case, the problem is gone.
I would recommend you to open another ticket here to solve your previos problem with Wayland.
Please, forgive me for this frustrating answer to your question - but it was what worked for me: turn Wayland on and do not spend any more time with Xorg incompatibilities.
Good luck!

Hi, i just gave up and went back do wayland and enabled Xorg only for Eclipse IDE. Is just a crap usability with minor crashes but at least don't freezes my entire system.
